# Error shows Method is undefined when I clearly have it written in the class it is referring to, in Java?

Tags: java, methods, event-handling

I have removed good chunks of my code as it is irrelevant to this issue.
This is my TRAPSCalendar class:

```
import java.awt.Event;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TRAPSCalendar {
    private ArrayList<Event> calendar;
    
    public TRAPSCalendar() {
        calendar = new ArrayList<Event>(); //create object
    }
    
    public Event get(java.lang.String name) { // the list of event names 
        for (int i = 0; i < calendar.size(); i++) {
            if (calendar.get(i).getEventName().equals(name)) {  // getEventName() from Event.java
                return calendar.get(i);
            }
            
        }
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

There is an error at
`if (calendar.get(i).getEventName().equals(name))...`
The method getEventName() is undefined for the type Event.

However, in my Event.java, I have:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Event {
    String eventName;
    String date;
    String eventVenue;
    int venueCapacity;
    int ticketsSold;
    int ticketPrice;
    int overhead;

    public Event() {
        //create
    }
//other methods for other things
    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and it continues to show the error.

Comment: It looks to me like you may have imported AWTs `Event` class rather than your own, this is shown on the first line of your included code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first line of `TRAPSCalendar`, you `import java.awt.Event;` This is why you are not working with your own `Event` class, but with `java.awt.Event`. The error message comes up because there is no `java.awt.Event.getEventName()` method implemented.

In order to fix this issue, remove the `import java.awt.Event;` statement and import your own `Event` class instead. That should do the trick.

Comment: OH my god. Thank you so much. I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 3):

You are using java.awt.Event rather than your own Event.